# QDockWidget without a title bar

Tags: c++, qt

I want to delete the title bar of QDockWidget completely. Is there any method to do this except the stylesheet?

Comment: Not really sure if this works out of the box, usually you need the title so that the widget when stacked has a tab-label. The question is  rather what you want to achieve with this, you can easily hide the close button etc. if thats your concern.

Comment: I have already hidden the close button. What I wanted to achieve is to gain from space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable window decorations (title) you have to set several flags in widget constructor, like this:

```
drawer::drawer(QWidget *parent) :
    QDockWidget(parent, Qt::Window | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint |
        Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint | Qt::FramelessWindowHint) /**/
{}
```

This disabled title and removes window from taskbar.
For more information use [Window Flags](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop)

Comment: Try next: Qt::Window | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint

Comment: [Window Flags Example](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/widgets-windowflags.html). You have it in your Qt build in examples/widgets. There you can test different flags combinations and find what combination will disable title bar (my flags set works both on linux and windows-mingw).

Answer (score 32):

```
dockWidget->setTitleBarWidget(new QWidget());
```

Comment: That worked for me. What about QWidget()'s missing parent - who should I attach there?

Comment: i guess dockwidget will take its ownership, so leave it

Comment: or you can do it like this `dockWidget->setTitleBarWidget(new QWidget(dockWidget));`